# Munkres' Topology - Theorem 15.2

Tags: general-topology

Theorem 15.2 of Topology by Munkres states:

> The collection
> $$\mathcal{S} = \{\pi_1^{-1}(U)|U \text{ open in X}\} \cup \{\pi_2^{-1}(V)|V \text{ open in Y}\}$$
> is a subbasis for the product topology on $X \times Y$.

He defined $\pi_1:X \times Y \rightarrow X$ by $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ and similarly $\pi_2: X \times Y \rightarrow Y$ by $\pi_2(x,y)=y.$

It seems to be there is no restriction on the set from $X \times Y$ that is being mapped. So for an example, consider the set $X = \{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{3,4\}$ with topologies $\mathcal{T}_X = \{\phi,\{1\}, \{1,2\}\}$ and $\mathcal{T}_Y = \{\phi, \{3\}, \{3,4\}\}$.

Consider $\{2\} \times \{4\} = \{(2,4)\}$. The mapping $\pi_1(2,4)=2$ and $\pi_2(2,4)=4$. For one thing, these mappings do not give sets, rather an element of $X$ or $Y$. Shouldn't they be sets? Since only sets like $\{2\}$ or $\{4\}$ can be open but not an element like $2$ and $4$.

Moreover, $\{2\}$ and $\{4\}$ are not open in their respective topologies. So their pre-image would just be the empty set, and an empty set cannot be a subbasis which means I am applying this theorem wrong. I would like to know where am I going wrong? When he defines the mapping $\pi_1:X \times Y \rightarrow X$ does he mean the set $X \times Y$ or any subset of $X \times Y$?

Also, could you please provide an example where the subbasis generated by this theorem is not a basis? It is appreciated if the example is for finite sets.

Comment: I don’t have the book, but I suspect that at the end of the statement there should be “product topology on $X\times Y$”, rather than “on $X$”.

Comment: You are right. I will edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that your post (in my version of Munkres this is correct) contains a typo. $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis of $X \times Y$ and not of $X$.

In your case:
$$\{\pi_1^{-1}(U): U \in \tau_X\}= \{\pi_1^{-1}(\emptyset),\pi_1^{-1}(\{1\}), \pi_1^{-1}(\{1,2\})\}= \{\emptyset, \{1\}\times Y, X \times Y\}$$
Similarly

$$\{\pi_2^{-1}(U): U \in \tau_X\}= \{\pi_2^{-1}(\emptyset),\pi_2^{-1}(\{1\}), \pi_2^{-1}(\{1,2\})\}= \{\emptyset, X\times \{3\}, X \times Y\}$$

Thus, $$\mathcal{S}= \{\emptyset, X \times Y, \{1\}\times Y, X\times \{3\}\}$$
$$=\{\emptyset, \{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)\}, \{(1,3),(1,4)\}, \{(1,3),(2,3)\}\}$$
is a subbasis of $X \times Y$.

It is not a basis, because a basis must contain $\{(1,3)\}= \{1\}\times \{3\}$.

Comment: I fixed the typo. It seems there is a typo in your answer. It should be $X$ not $\{X\}$ in the line where you find $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Would we turn into problem if $\pi_1: X \rightarrow X \times Y$ is defined by $\pi_1(x)=(x,y)$ and similarly for $\pi_2$ and then $\mathcal{S} = \{\pi_1(U) | U \in \mathcal{T}_X \} \cup \{ \pi_2(V) | V \in \mathcal{T}_Y \}$ be a subbasis for $X \times Y$?

Comment: @Rob Thanks for spotting that typo. For your second question, what is $y$? Is it a fixed element in $Y$? In general, that will definitely not be true because in that way $\mathcal{S}$ will get opens that contain points with second coordinates $y$ and there is no reason why this should hold. It is easy to find a counterexample this way.